# Why does JTA have a Transaction and a UserTransaction interfaces to represent transaction?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jta

The JTA api defines two interfaces

- Transaction http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/Transaction.html
- UserTransaction http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html

The classes have some methods that have the same name and appear to have the same semantics, at least from reading the javadoc.

Why does JTA needs to define two interfaces to represent a transaction?

Comment: For an excellent write up on this topic see this post by the creator of Bitronix (a standalone transaction manager): http://blog.bitronix.be/2011/02/why-we-need-jta-2-0/